# Android Dokka and multiple markdown files

Tags: android, kotlin-dokka, dokka

I have a module called "Machin" and I want to generate HTML documentation using ./gradlew ./gradlew dokkaHtml.
It works but I have some markdown files (.md) in my documentation which I want to convert to html using Dokka. The issue is that there is just one md file converted, the one with "# Module Machin" at the begining is working and is convected to an index.html file.

In my build.gradle, I have that:

```
includes.from("Documentation/Machin.md")
includes.from("Documentation/GettingStarted.md")
```

I want to generate an index.html for Machin.md, this is working well, but I also want Dokka to gerenate a GettingStarted.html and want a link in index.html which refers to GettingStarted.html.

I tried to use # Module Getting Started
and tried to use a markdown link like this :

```
[Getting Started](./GettingStarted.md)
```

But Dokka does not generate my GettingStarted.html and obviously, the link is not working.

Is there a way to achieve that using Dokka or is it just impossible ?

Thanks!

Comment: I have had the same question for a while and not found the answer. I think it's just impossible via standard dokka functionality.